# 1 less, 2 fewer... When to use either/or

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

The statement reads - "...the length is less than 20 meters...".  Should this be fewer than, or is it correct to state 'less than'?

I believe that it should be fewer as metres is what I am dealing with (the subject), however, others differ...

Answer (score 3):

"20 meters" is a single concept describing one interval, not a countable group of individual meters. "less than" is correct.

Comment: Thanks for that, I am now 600million gbp worse off as that is the bet that I had on it!  Perhaps for a share of my 600milliion you could change your answer?!

Comment: +1. @Hooray: I will give you the answer you want and will settle for fewer than 600 million GBP. Just say the word.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Better get that in dollars or euros.

Comment: How about pesetas or lira, I hear that they are the 'new currencies' after the demise of the euro?  But, I digress, seriously can someone come up with an answer that I can put forward in order to not have to declare eternal bankruptcy...

Comment: I would really like to upvote this answer, however, without attaining an upvote or two myself I do not have sufficient reputation  to vote - HELP!